# Deployment to Azure failing, need help debugging it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, azure, azure-web-roles

I have an asp.net mvc 4 application, and I'm deploying it to Azure, It's deploying successfully but when I add a package from NuGet (Postal 0.8.2) it's breaking my deployment. I need help figuring out what's wrong so I can report the problem to the project.

When I deploy the app with that package the server keeps cycling:

> 10:10:39 AM - Instance 0 of role Biosign is creating the virtual machine
>
> 10:11:12 AM - Instance 0 of role Biosign is starting the virtual machine
>
> 10:12:50 AM - Instance 0 of role Biosign is in an unknown state
>
> 10:13:23 AM - Instance 0 of role Biosign is busy
>
> 10:17:06 AM - Instance 0 of role Biosign is cycling

[image]

If I check directly in the server with remote desktop I see this two errors repeating multiple times in Event Viewer (inside "Web Server (IIS)":

> The application '/' belonging to site '1273337584' has an invalid AppPoolId 'aef747de-29d0-4deb-8beb-84765ef61887' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored.
>
> Site 1 was disabled because the root application defined for the site is invalid. See the previous event log message for information about why the root application is invalid.

I also see this Application Error in Event Viewer:

> Faulting application name: WaHostBootstrapper.exe, version: 2.0.1196.19, time stamp: 0x514bb531
> Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16420, time stamp: 0x505ab405
> Exception code: 0xc0000374
> Fault offset: 0x00000000000ea485
> Faulting process id: 0x67c
> Faulting application start time: 0x01ce5aedc740e826
> Faulting application path: E:\base\x64\WaHostBootstrapper.exe
> Faulting module path: D:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
> Report Id: 0be8db8b-c6e1-11e2-93ef-00155d44b470
> Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

The strange thing is that if I open the app in the server it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a local virtual machine and install an evaluation version of [Visual Studio Ultimate](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads). Debug with [IntelliTrace on Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683671.aspx). Intellitrace is the first place to start with roles that don't start — unfortunately it is only available in the ultimate version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Intellitrace did show me the exception inmediately. Thanks.
(I'll give you the bounty as soon as I can)

Comment: @Escobar5 Could you tell me what your particular error was? I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: @rattrick1 sorry, I don't remember, try with intellitrace if you can, or try with diagnostics: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/

Comment: For those who don't want to invest in VS Ultimate, you can get a high degree of insight with the AzureTools: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/10/03/troubleshooting-scenario-7-role-recycling.aspx

Answer (score 2):

**I have same error:**

*IIS log*

The application '/' belonging to site '1273337584' has an invalid AppPoolId '3f3649d0-fa6f-4244-8d28-d9e7b904bd0f' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored.

*Application Logs*

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http'
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost'

**Fixed** adding System.Web.Http.dll and System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll (Copy Local in VS)!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone:

I struggled with this error long time too, and finally find a solution. What caused the error in my case was that one DLL I was using, was in 32-bit but IIS in Azure requires 64-bit DLLs to be used by default. 
Of course it's possible to set AppPool to accept 32-bit libraries. This didn't worked in my case. Only thing which helped, was to use 64-bit DLLs in web appl.

Bw, Sami