# Unable to reach web site locally on Azure web role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am deploying multiple web sites on Windows Azure cloud service on Single web role. I have added required binding and host file entries. when I run ping command I am getting the response as well.

However when RDP to VM and browse the site locally on VM as **localhost** 
 it is not reachable and showing 404 not found.

Error from IIS events

```
The application '/' belonging to site '1' has an invalid AppPoolId 'DefaultAppPool' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored.
```

Answer (score 1):

> when RDP to VM and browse the site locally on VM as localhost it is not reachable and showing 404 not found.

I [access the desktop of your web role running in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop-new-portal) and add a new Web site to your Web server, I can browse the site locally. If possible, you can try to create a new web site to server static html files and check if it works fine, or you can share us the detailed information of bindings and your application.

**Add a website:**

[image]

**Settings:**

[image]

**Application pool:**

[image]

**Browse site locally:**

[image]

> The application '/' belonging to site '1' has an invalid AppPoolId 'DefaultAppPool' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored.

Some community members encounter and post similar issue in [this so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776264/deployment-to-azure-failing-need-help-debugging-it), you can check if any .dll files are missing or 32-bit libraries are used.